# Ada Digits Confusion

Tags: precision, ada, digits

I have been doing some reading, and I'm having a tough time understanding how to interpret something that is a "digits x".
I.E.

```
type something is digits 6
```

I get that it's 6 digits of precision, but I guess what has me mixed up is what does that mean.

1) Y.XXXXXX (6X's),

2) XXX.XXX (Any number of digits, just will always be 6 of them counting both fore and aft the mantissa)

...

I'm just trying to understand what a range of something that is digits 6 (or digits n to be more generic), is there a formula I can simply plug into to determine what my ranges are on a type that is some number of digits?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A type declared with `digits` is a floating-point type, similar to `Float` or `Long_Float`.

The `6` is "the minimum number of significant decimal digits required for 
the floating point type".  For example, all the following will be represented reasonably accurately (but not *exactly*):

```
type My_Real is digits 6;
X: My_Real := 1.23456;
Y: My_Real := 12345.6;
Z: My_Real := 1.23456E7;
```

In practice, there are usually just 2 or 3 underlying floating-point types on a given system.  The compiler will choose an appropriate one as the underlying type for your declaration.  In practice, two types declared with `digits 2` and `digits 6` will probably have exactly the same representation and precision.

Understanding the phrase "not *exactly*" requires an understanding of floating-point that's well beyond the scope of a single question, but if you're familiar with floating-point in other languages, it's the same general idea.

If you want a general understanding of what floating-point is and how it works, the [Wikipedia Article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) isn't bad.  A much more advanced treatment is David Goldberg's classic paper "What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic", available [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) as a web page and [here](http://gicl.cs.drexel.edu/wiki-data/images/0/03/P5-goldberg-Floating-Point.pdf) as a PDF.

Comment: Is it possible to get also a W: My_Real := 123456.0?

Comment: @onaclov2000: Of course.  You might want to read [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point).  You might *eventually* want to read Goldberg's "What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic".